# Synchronizing screen output with mutex and pthread

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex

I'm playing with a fairly simple C example. The program creates two threads and starts them in parallel. Each thread is designed to modify a global variable using a Mutex, and print out the value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int A=10;
pthread_mutex_t M;

void *codice_Th1(void *arg) {
  int i;
  for (i=0; i<10;i++){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&M);
    printf("Thread %s: ", (char *)arg);
    A++;
    printf("A = %d \n", A);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&M);
    sleep(1);
  }
  pthread_exit(0);
}

void *codice_Th2(void *arg) {
  int i;
  for (i=0; i<10;i++){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&M);
    printf("Thread %s: ", (char *)arg);
    A--;
    printf("A = %d \n", A);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&M);
    sleep(1);
  }
  pthread_exit(0);
}
```

The `main()` simply creates the thread, and join the main thread with thread 1 and 2.

```
int main(){
  pthread_t th1, th2;
  ...
}
```

What bothers me, is that I get the following output

```
Thread th1: Thread th2: A = 11
A = 10
Thread th1: A = 11
Thread th2: A = 10
Thread th1: Thread th2: A = 11
A = 10
Thread th1: Thread th2: A = 11
A = 10
Thread th2: Thread th1: A = 9
A = 10
Thread th1: A = 11
Thread th2: A = 10
```

whereas I would expect every line to execute the `printf` statements in sequence, given they are inside a mutex.

In other words, I can't understand the ouput

```
Thread th2: Thread th1: A = 9
```

I would expect always something similar to

```
Thread NAME: A = VALUE
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Never mind, I believe I found the issue. I did not initialize the Mutex with `pthread_mutex_init(&M, NULL);` before using it.

Setting

```
int main(){
  pthread_t th1, th2;
  int ret;

  pthread_mutex_init(&M, NULL);
```

fixed the issue. I assume using `pthread_mutex_init` is a requirement. Unfortunately, skipping the mutex initialization din't produce any warning or error. The script silently compiled.

Comment: In the future include the entirety (or at least the relevant parts) of your `main` function so we can find these errors too :)

Comment: @Daniel You are absolutely right. I mistakenly assumed the `main()` was simple enough that did not deserved to be posted.

Comment: It can't produce a warning or error at compile-time... How your compiler would know that this function should be called? How would it find if it is really called? Remember that not initializing variables is a very common mistake in C, it is not forbidden. It is UB to use them. This is exactly what happened to you with your mutex.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès The compiler is not able to understand if they would ever been used, but it could still statically detect the presence of a method call that involves the mutex, and warn you about a possible "not initialized mutex invocation". But I don't know `C` enough to prove my assumption would make sense. :)

Comment: No he can't. You are thinking about too simple situations. Think about initializing in a function, using it in another... If the calls to these functions are somehow complex your compiler will not be able to determine if they are correctly called.